# Pandas Merge Operation on two different dataTable?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have 2 different data table in given format:
[image: dataTable1]

[image: DataTable2]

Now i want two merge this dataTable in one in which last colum of dataTable1(number and string) and 1st Colum of dataTable2(number) is having common value. i want to merge in this common value and dont want any other row which is not there in both table. i am using pandas for that and my code is

```
import numpy as np`
import pandas as pd
sellOrder = pd.read_excel('Europe_SO.xlsx')
purchaseOrder = pd.read_excel('Atlas PO.xlsx')
final = purchaseOrder.merge(sellOrder, left_on = 'EBELN', right_on = 'BSTNK', how='inner', indicator=True)
```

But i am getting empty table with no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is columns `EBELN` and `BSTNK` has different `dtypes` in both `DataFrames` so no match.

Check it by:

```
print (sellOrder['EBELN'].dtype)
print (purchaseOrder['BSTNK'].dtype)
```

So need convert both columns to `int` or both to `str`.

```
sellOrder['EBELN'] = sellOrder['EBELN'].astype(int)
purchaseOrder['BSTNK'] = purchaseOrder['BSTNK'].astype(int)
```

Or:

```
sellOrder['EBELN'] = sellOrder['EBELN'].astype(str)
purchaseOrder['BSTNK'] = purchaseOrder['BSTNK'].astype(str)
```

Comment: yes One is object and one is string. Its worked fine now .thanks